# Can't create a table in mysql, using mysql workbench

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table using mysql workbench and I get the message. I am using ubuntu 12.04

> 17:00:02 Apply changes to pygm_allvideoshare_weights  Unknown column
>   'Tables_in_pygmaxia2.gr' in 'where clause'

I can create tables in other databases but not in that specific. Whats wrong with mysql workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of the database from pygmaxia2.gr to pygmaxia2 and now I can create tables in the database. I guess databases can't have .something in there name.. so, thanx anyway